# Optimisation solver(Excel) analog in Python

Tags: python, optimization, solver

I have my cumulative bike riding time for the first 14 days

```
time = [2.29,2.29,3.15,3.89,4.72,5.21,5.21,5.55,5.8,6.18,6.44,6.9,7.11,7.32]
```

I know this values described by equation

```
y(t) = a*ln(t+b)
```

Where:

t - day of my riding

a,b - coefficients to be founded

I need to find the correct coefficients a and b for 14 days values with optimization sum squares of deviations(pretty simple with solver in Excel). And then predict 30 day value. How to find this coefficients in python?
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: just confirming that I understood correctly - you really want to do the best fit using a natural logarithm function? The basic recipe is to linearise the problem and then apply scipy.stats.linregress to it. If you could confirm that I didn't misinterpret the question, I'll post the full code

Comment: Actually - sorry, but my maths is letting me down on this one. I don't think I know how to transform this equation form into a linear variant. Tried any way I could, got logs and exponentials coming out of my ears, but can't linearise it. Why not try a y = a*x + b fit?

Comment: @DmytroBugayev it's all about my task) I need to optimise log function. And it's not nessesary to use all points. We can use for example only 3rd(3.15), 7th(5.21), 10th(6.18)and 14(7.32) days points.

Comment: So you *could* use `scipy` `minimize` to attack this, but I'm curious why you have chosen that for for `y(t)`?  If you want to fit a curve that you believe is governed by a logarithmic function, the standard form is `y(t) = a + b ln(t)` which does have a linear transform and solves immediately

Comment: Thanks guys. I've solved my problem with scipy.optimaze.curve_fit